# How to put a set of Hexadecimal number as a String?

Tags: python

I want  to compute the `key` of round 10 based another `key`, It works very well if `ikk` is a string, so how to convert it into a string?

```
def test():
    ##### ikk=  '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f'  ===> It works!!!
    ikk= 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
    ik=str(ikk)
    data = [re.findall('..', item) for item in key.split('\n')]
    for item in data:
        if item:
            result = [int(x, 16) for x in item]
            print(result)
            result = keyScheduleRounds(result, 0, 10)
            tt=''.join(["%02x"%d for d in result])
            print(tt)
```

**Error that I found:**

```
ik= str(000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f)                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: It looks `000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f` is not a valid number.

Comment: @taras it is my key, it is correct I just need to put it as string:  '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f', this is my problem.

Comment: No, you can use it as a hex if you tell Python that;s a hex. like this: ikk= 0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f

Answer (score 1):

If ikk is an hexadecimal number (and it looks like), try this way : `ikk = 0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f`. Notice the `0x` at the beginning that will tell python this is an hexadecimal number, and not a decimal number.

Comment: It give me this error: data = [re.findall('..', item) for item in key.split('\n')]
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Because you're trying to use the split function on a non-string object.

Comment: @tierrytestu what are you trying to do exactly with this hex number ?

Comment: @CédricJulien  My goal is to compute a derivation key based in AES protocol.

Comment: I am using the same code but by reading keys from a text file and that works very well

Answer (score 1):

set ik :

```
ik= bytearray.fromhex("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f").decode()
```

This will convert hexadecimal to string. 
Full code is written below.

```
def test():
    ik = bytearray.fromhex("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f").decode()
    data = [re.findall('..', item) for item in key.split('\n')]
    for item in data:
        if item:
            result = [int(x, 16) for x in item]
            print(result)
            result = keyScheduleRounds(result, 0, 10)
            tt=''.join(["%02x"%d for d in result])
            print(tt)
```

Comment: It gives me this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\x00' in position 0: invalid decimal Unicode string
>>>